# Why isn't [disabled] = 'enableSubmit' disabling my button in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a problem that seems to be super simple yet I can't seem to make it working.

In my component I have a Boolean variable that is called enableSubmit its initialized like this:   `enableSubmit: boolean = false;`

In my template I have a button which is defined as this:
  enableSubmit: boolean = false;

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled] ='enableSubmit'>Aanvragen</button>
```

Yet when I run the template the Aanvragen button is still enabled? How is this possible?

Comment: why the hate people... I'm new to Angular

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you set `disabled` to be equal to `true`. It should be vice versa, as you are setting whether the button is **disabled**, not *enabled*

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I will highly recommended to use double quotes notation inside the template.
its not working because [disabled] attribute only work when its value is true but in your case it is false, Just set **enableSubmit: boolean = true;**